New Transactions aren't added to Account Balances after Import Error
I made an error and accidentally imported last month's transaction twice. As a result, I had all transactions recorded twice. This was easy to rectify by deleting the doubles, but I couldn't solve a different error: The account balance went "0.00" with the first imported transaction and stayed "0.00" for all transactions thereafter. I tried the check & repair action to no avail.
What can I do? (The old file got written over, so I can't go back to last month's data file as well).

what software are you using?
